# MODx Plugin does not get fired (with no event)

Tags: plugins, modx

I created a test plugin and activated **ALL events** in the "System-Events" Tab. The Plugin looks like so:

```
<?php
error_log('test_plugin: ' . $modx->event->name);
```

thats it.

I'm following the error.log via `tail -f /var/log/error.log` and I get several entries when I'm reloading a page in the **backend** (which is perfect)

```
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnHandleRequest, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnManagerPageInit, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnBeforeManagerPageInit, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnManagerPageBeforeRender, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnPluginFormRender, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnParseDocument, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnPluginFormPrerender, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:08 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnManagerPageAfterRender, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=1
[Tue Nov 03 21:07:10 2015] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] test_plugin: OnResourceToolbarLoad, referer: http://my.domain.de/manager/index.php?a=13&id=13
```

But when loading a page in **FRONT-END** I get **NOTHING AT ALL**.

Any ideas? I'm using **Revo 2.2.14-pl**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was a **caching Problem**. Solved it using the [*CacheClear*-snippet](http://bobsguides.com/cache-clear-tutorial.html) from Bob Ray.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the MODX log for this:

```
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG);
$modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, 'test_plugin: ' . $modx->event->name);
```

You could use a different `tail -f /path/to/your/webroot/core/cache/logs/error.log` with that.

Comment: An (incomplete) list of MODX system events could be found in the RTFM: https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/plugins/system-events

Comment: i activated **all available events** in the system events tab

Comment: but it's about the execution of the event. even a `die()` won't do anything

Comment: Do you have an output that is generated by MODX? Is the page cached (even then some events should be triggered)?

Comment: MODx shows the site as usual! As I said, even with `die()` nothing happens. I disabled all caches, deleted the cache via site menu... but still nothing :(

Comment: Also something to be aware of is that not all of the events listed in modx actually do anything. some while listed do not actually do anything.